# Can't rebase Fedora 35 to 36

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I am using Fedora 35 right now and would like to switch to version 36 but can't do that:

```bsh
rpm-ostree rebase fedora:fedora/36/x86_64/silverblue
⠤ Receiving objects; 99% (366/367) 10,2 MB/s 214,5 MB 
Receiving objects; 99% (366/367) 10,2 MB/s 214,5 MB... done
Checking out tree f470509... done
Enabled rpm-md repositories: fedora-cisco-openh264 updates fedora rpmfusion-free-updates rpmfusion-free rpmfusion-nonfree-updates rpmfusion-nonfree copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:lukenukem:asus-linux updates-archive
Updating metadata for 'updates'... done
Updating metadata for 'rpmfusion-free-updates'... done
Updating metadata for 'rpmfusion-nonfree-updates'... done
Updating metadata for 'copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:lukenukem:asus-linux'... done
Updating metadata for 'updates-archive'... done
Importing rpm-md... done
rpm-md repo 'fedora-cisco-openh264' (cached); generated: 2022-04-07T16:52:38Z solvables: 4
rpm-md repo 'updates'; generated: 2022-02-08T18:40:57Z solvables: 0
rpm-md repo 'fedora' (cached); generated: 2022-05-01T10:06:39Z solvables: 67991
rpm-md repo 'rpmfusion-free-updates'; generated: 2022-02-17T15:50:15Z solvables: 0
rpm-md repo 'rpmfusion-free' (cached); generated: 2022-04-29T12:28:10Z solvables: 506
rpm-md repo 'rpmfusion-nonfree-updates'; generated: 2022-02-17T15:50:29Z solvables: 0
rpm-md repo 'rpmfusion-nonfree' (cached); generated: 2022-04-29T12:52:47Z solvables: 225
rpm-md repo 'copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:lukenukem:asus-linux'; generated: 2022-02-10T06:11:29Z solvables: 4
rpm-md repo 'updates-archive'; generated: 2022-02-11T15:18:19Z solvables: 0
Resolving dependencies... done
error: Could not depsolve transaction; 3 problems detected:
 Problem 1: package kernel-devel-matched-5.17.3-302.fc36.x86_64 requires kernel-core = 5.17.3-302.fc36, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package akmods-0.5.7-7.fc36.noarch requires (kernel-devel-matched if kernel-core), but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both kernel-core-5.17.3-302.fc36.x86_64 and kernel-core-5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64
  - package akmod-nvidia-3:510.60.02-1.fc36.x86_64 requires akmods, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
 Problem 2: package kmod-nvidia-3:510.60.02-1.fc36.x86_64 requires akmod-nvidia = 3:510.60.02-1.fc36, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda-3:510.60.02-1.fc36.x86_64 requires nvidia-kmod >= 3:510.60.02, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package akmod-nvidia-3:510.60.02-1.fc36.x86_64 requires akmods, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package akmods-0.5.7-7.fc36.noarch requires (kernel-devel-matched if kernel-core), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kernel-devel-matched-5.17.3-302.fc36.x86_64 requires kernel-core = 5.17.3-302.fc36, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both kernel-core-5.17.3-302.fc36.x86_64 and kernel-core-5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64
  - package kernel-5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64 requires kernel-core-uname-r = 5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
 Problem 3: package kmod-nvidia-3:510.60.02-1.fc36.x86_64 requires akmod-nvidia = 3:510.60.02-1.fc36, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:510.60.02-1.fc36.x86_64 requires nvidia-kmod >= 3:510.60.02, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package akmod-nvidia-3:510.60.02-1.fc36.x86_64 requires akmods, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package akmods-0.5.7-7.fc36.noarch requires (kernel-devel-matched if kernel-core), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kernel-devel-matched-5.17.3-302.fc36.x86_64 requires kernel-core = 5.17.3-302.fc36, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both kernel-core-5.17.3-302.fc36.x86_64 and kernel-core-5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64
  - package kernel-modules-5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64 requires kernel-uname-r = 5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:510.60.02-1.fc36.x86_64 requires xorg-x11-drv-nvidia(x86-64) = 3:510.60.02, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
```

Not sure what is happening here to be honest.

Additional info:

```bsh
uname -r
5.17.5-200.fc35.x86_64
```

```bsh
rpm-ostree status
State: idle
Deployments:
● fedora:fedora/35/x86_64/silverblue
                   Version: 35.20220505.0 (2022-05-05T06:22:10Z)
                BaseCommit: 955f0c8da93ec5c97ba5f5999f9061ec9a0c7fe41c14cb5ab6f64fadcca0c511
              GPGSignature: Valid signature by 787EA6AE1147EEE56C40B30CDB4639719867C58F
       RemovedBasePackages: firefox 100.0-2.fc35
           LayeredPackages: akmod-nvidia asusctl docker-compose podman-docker rpmfusion-free-release rpmfusion-nonfree-release tlp tlp-rdw xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power

  fedora:fedora/35/x86_64/silverblue
                   Version: 35.20220503.0 (2022-05-03T14:12:49Z)
                BaseCommit: aef35d7e7acf22ce7251f954679c73047cd889371d91dd21b228ce7ac0688b27
              GPGSignature: Valid signature by 787EA6AE1147EEE56C40B30CDB4639719867C58F
           LayeredPackages: akmod-nvidia asusctl docker-compose podman-docker rpmfusion-free-release rpmfusion-nonfree-release tlp tlp-rdw xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power

  fedora:fedora/35/x86_64/silverblue
                   Version: 35.20220503.0 (2022-05-03T14:12:49Z)
                BaseCommit: aef35d7e7acf22ce7251f954679c73047cd889371d91dd21b228ce7ac0688b27
              GPGSignature: Valid signature by 787EA6AE1147EEE56C40B30CDB4639719867C58F
           LayeredPackages: akmod-nvidia asusctl rpmfusion-free-release rpmfusion-nonfree-release tlp tlp-rdw xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power
                    Pinned: yes
```

What can I do to update to newer version?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've followed the instructions on pinning your current version, go ahead and do the following.

```
rpm-ostree reset
```

This will remove all the packages that have all sorts of dependencies on 35.

```
rpm-ostree rebase fedora:fedora/36/x86_64/silverblue
```

This performs your upgrade.

Now `rpm-ostree install` all your $oftware. To figure out what those packages are, `rpm-ostree status` will show you the pinned versions and the layered packages. If you used any fusion packages (which you probably did), you'll need to add those repositories before you can install. [RPM Fusion Config instructions](https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration)

Comment: well, I believe what happened is I tried to rebase to fedora with newer kernel which was not yet supported by nvidia drivers since when I tried to rebase after official 36 launch everything went smoothly